# ¿Porque no puedo agregar elementos a un arreglo?

Tags: javascript, array, promesas

resulta que estoy haciendo peticiones a una API de Rick and Morty y estoy intentando agregar los nombres de los personajes que me retorna a un arreglo pero pasa algo que no logro entender.
Como pueden ver los datos me los trae perfectamente así como los nombres de los personajes.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cosa es que en el .then() hago un for llamando a una función varias veces que lo único que hace es hacer un push a un arreglo vacío que tengo ya definido arriba[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora hago otro arreglo, lo defino dentro del .then() y le hago la misma operacion.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan la unica diferencia es que un arreglo esta dentro del .then() y otro en el scope global, ahora hago un console.log() de ambos arreglos. Tambien me extraña que el arreglo del scope global pareciera no tener nada pero cuando lo desglozas segun estan los nombres que deberian estar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pareciera que no hay ningún problema, pero cuando intento acceder a alguna posicion del array en el scope global simplemente no me lo permite. Me da undefined.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si hago un push al arreglo del scope global me lo toma como la primera posición,
Y si muestro mi array o accedo a una de sus posiciones desde un setTimeout() funciona como deberia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No entiendo que pasa, es sumamente extraño y jamás me había pasado algo similar

Comment: El código en imagen no es bien recibido, por favor pon el código como texto, edita tu pregunta

Comment: Concuerdo con Chistian. Ya deberías sabes que no se incluyen imagenes, a la siguiente debes pasar el código para que a nosotros sea más facil la lectura y el replicado.

Comment: Lo tendre en cuenta para la próxima, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido al mundo asíncrono de JS. Este es el algoritmo que yo veo

1. Defino variable `nombres`
2. Hago mi función asíncrona
3. Invoco mi función asíncrona y meto los nombres
4. `Hago console.log( nombres )`

El problema está en el paso 3 y 4. Estas mandando a llamar la función, pero como es asíncrona a JS no le importa lo que regrese, al final tendrá un callback. Y salta al paso 4, pero la función sigue trabajando en traer los datos. Por eso cuando haces `console.log()` te da `undefined`, a pesar que estas empujando los valores, el console.log se lanzó antes de traer los valores

Repliqué tu código con algunas adecuaciones te dejo documentado el código

```js
// La ruta de tu API
const API_URL = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/';

// Crea una función async/await
const getCharacters = async () => {
    // Mete try/catch para manejo de errores
    try {
    // Si todo sale bien regresa el resultado
    const result = await fetch( API_URL )
    .then( result => result.json() );
    return result;
    // Error en caso contrario
  } catch( e ) {
    console.error( 'Ocurrió un error: ',  e );
    return undefined;
  }
    
  
};

// Crea una función anónima autoejecutable
( async () => {
    // Pide la información
    const nombresAPI = await getCharacters();
    if ( nombresAPI ) {
    // No necesitas un FOR, con el .map() hace el trabajo por ti
    const nombres = nombresAPI.results.map( element => element.name );
    console.log( nombres );
  }
})();
```

Comment: Genial muchas gracias, jamás se me ocurrió que llegara a se eso, apenas estoy aprendiendo promesas por lo que no conozco async y await muy bien, me pondré a investigarlo